# What does "ну-ка" means?

Tags: словоупотребление, сленг

I've seen this a lot in a comedy series that I'm watching.

For example in a situation when the boss yell at some unknown guys to get out of the house he says:

"**Ну-ка**, пошли вон отсюда!"

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian. SE! The meaning of this phrase is readily available in many reference sources, e.g. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0. If there's a particular reason you doubt these sources, please clarify it in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearest translation of **ну-ка** into english is **come on** and it is true (i'm native speaker)

just try some translators before asking, cause I wrote big post here that describes deep meaning of that word before accidentally translated it into english :D